# Why is my method not recognizing my object member?

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a "generic" class for a D3 force graph.
When the `graphTick()` function is called (or any other method it seems...) the member values of the class are `undefined` as if the method was not bound to that instance.

I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the JS way of writing a class (I'm from a C++ background) or if I'm misusing the D3 framework. Maybe both?

I've tried to replace....

```
simulation.on("tick", this.graphTick)
```

...by:

```
simulation.on("tick", function(){ 
    /*graphTick implementation*/ 
})
```

But then it looked like it was called by some anomymous object from D3, so I'm thinking my problem is probably more about JS syntax.

Got a Codepen setup with this class and a quick test: https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/VGLNLa

Comment: Your relevant code should be embedded in the question.

Comment: @trincot I added a big comment in the CodePen indicating where the error appears, I did not put it in here because I found that the function generating the errors alone was not enough context for this problem

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. All necessary context should be *in* the question, not behind a link.

Comment: Right, the code should be *in* the question, not linked to off-site.  The codepen is welcome, but the code should still be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a JavaScript class, which is quite uncommon in D3 codes. There is no problem in using classes per se, but you have to take extra care when dealing with the `this` keyword.

The issue in your code is the value of `this` inside the `graphTick` function: in the `"tick"` listener, `this` is the simulation itself. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_on):

> When a specified event is dispatched, each listener will be invoked with the `this` context as the simulation.

You can easily see it by yourself if you do a `console.log(this)` inside the function. You'll get:

```
{tick: function, restart: function, stop: function, nodes: function, etc...}
```

And that explains why both your attempts didn't work: in both of them, `this` is the simulation itself.

The solution is simple, just pass the correct `this` to the `graphTick` function:

```
simulation.on("tick", this.graphTick.bind(this))
```

Here you can find more information about `bind()`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

And here is the updated code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgpxNX?editors=0010

Comment: Ow... ok! so `bind()` "locks" the `this` of `graphTick` to this specific class instance? Is there any risk that it might be statically bound to the class, and then become problematic when I have two or more Graph?

Comment: @VincentDM I don't think that this will happen... you can create a simple code with 2 or more instances, just to check this possible risk. Anyway, if that problem does arise at least now you know the cause, so you can think about other ways to fix it.